# MySQLi: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to pass a prepared query through a function that prepares the query and executes but I keep getting "`Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement`".

I cannot figure out what's wrong because I have the same number of variables as parameters.

**Query:**

```
UPDATE `users` SET fullname = ?,  telephone = ?,  email = ?,  company_name = ?,  company_addr2 = ?,  company_town = ?,  company_postcode = ?,  sra_registration = ?,  company_number = ?,  vat_registration = ?,  company_website = ?,  list_of_partners = ?,  my_staff = ? WHERE id = ?
```

**Params:**

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Ben Shepherd
            [1] => 071111111111
            [2] => john.doe@domain.com
            [3] => Company name
            [4] => addr2
            [5] => town
            [6] => postcode
            [7] => 123456
            [8] => 123456
            [9] => 123465
            [10] => http://www.somewebsite.com
            [11] => United Kingdom
            [12] => "[{\\\"staff_firstname\\\":\\\"John\\\",\\\"staff_surname\\\":\\\"Smith\\\",\\\"staff_email\\\":\\\"some@email.com\\\"},{\\\"staff_firstname\\\":\\\"Jane\\\",\\\"staff_surname\\\":\\\"Smith\\\",\\\"staff_email\\\":\\\"some2@email.com\\\"},{\\\"staff_firstname\\\":\\\"John 3\\\",\\\"staff_surname\\\":\\\"Smith 3\\\",\\\"staff_email\\\":\\\"john.smith3@email.com\\\"}]"
            [13] => 1
)
```

**Query function:**

```
    public static function query($query, $params = array())
    {           
        $params = !is_array($params) ? array($params) : $params;
        $data = array();

        $stmt = self::$i->prepare($query);

        if(!$stmt)
            return false;

        foreach($params as $value)
        {
            /* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
            switch( true )
            {
                case (is_double($value)):
                    $type = 'd';
                    break;

                case (is_int($value)):
                    $type = 'i';
                    break;

                default:
                case (is_string($value)):
                    $type = 's';
                    break;
            }
            $stmt->bind_param($type, $value);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->get_result();

        if(!$res) return false;

        while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        self::$customError = "";

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try encoding the variables prior to passing them to the MySQLi Query? e.g. the URL might cause problems due to the `//`... Just an idea.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to bind the parameters one by one.. but iirc have to bind them all at once

Comment: **Have a look at this source from a MySQLi Class on [GitHub](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php).** This'll surely help you out and teach you some vital details about this.

Comment: In your switch statement either take out case (is_string($value)): or move it before default: and make default: last

Comment: @MarkusHofmann **Please** do not advertise this awful piece of code here.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You could advise a mysqli wrapper that meets your requirements for advising it to a supposed novice.

Comment: @MarkusHofmann I have used that class before and all I had was problems with it

Comment: @BenShepherd Ok, I'm working on an improvement of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put all parameters into one `bind_param` call.

So move the `$stmt->bind_param($type, $value);` out of the foreach loop by using [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
<?php

public static function query($query, $params = array())
{           
    $params = !is_array($params) ? array($params) : $params;
    ...

    $types = array();
    foreach($params as $value)
    {
        /* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
        switch( true )
        {
            case (is_double($value)):
                $type = 'd';
                break;

            case (is_int($value)):
                $type = 'i';
                break;

            default:
            case (is_string($value)):
                $type = 's';
                break;
        }

        $types .= $type;
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($types), $params));
```